# Update the standard font style for the /ja-jp/ website to Microsoft's Meiryo font

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, sitecore

In my sitecore website there is some enhancement requested from client.
They want me to update the standard font style for the /ja-jp/ website to Microsoft's Meiryo font. This includes updating all HTML-based stylesheets related to all templates and sublayouts.

I have limited time so want to start with best suggestion instead of going with different approaches.

Further detail is :
In html I have

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

and what I need to update the font only for "Japanese" i.e

```
font-family: Meiryo ;
```

So what I am trying to do is adding below code into style sheet :

```
*:lang(ja) 
{
    font-family: Meiryo ;
}
```

but

```
  <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

is not letting me do this, and in case if I change html lang value to 'ja' than it changing entire website into Meiryo font, so is there any way so that I can have multiple html lang in main html.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, again I have to answer my own question :)
So, solution this time I got for this is :

I done following changes :

In my aspx file :

```
<html id="SomeID"  runat="server" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

In my style.css:

```
:lang(ja)
{
font-family: Meiryo;
}
```

And, in my aspx.cs file I have put following condition so that it works only when japan is selected in my sitecore website.

```
string requestedUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
           if (requestedUrl.ToLower().Contains("ja-jp"))
           {
              SomeID.Attributes.Add("lang", "ja");
         }
```

And its working for me now. Thanks !!

Comment: How is this different from my answer below? (apart from me using a class and you the lang attribute)

Comment: That's absolutely correct, just thought why not to provide multiple ways as per requirement. Your suggestion was cool, No offense :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the body tag when the language is ja-JP. E.g.:

```
<body class="jajp">
```

Then on the stylesheet add the font that you want only for that case. E.g.:

```
body.jajp * { font-family: Meiryo; }
```

Comment: That's cool, but what if some other country selected. I want this font only when country drop-down value is Japan, I know its easy but somehow not able to implement right now.

Comment: If you control the language with a drop-down, when it changes value, add/remove the body class accordingly